# How to display textarea over all elements?

Tags: css

I  have simple HTML code with one textarea element. When I click it I need to set opacity 0.8 to body and display textarea over body.

How to do this?

I tried:

```
body {
   opacity: 0.8;
z-index: 1
}

textarea {
   position:relative:
z-index:100;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set opacity on the body itself, all its children will get it too, so for that to work properly, it should look something like this, where you use a `.dimmer` to do the actually semi transparency.

This way you can have many items working similar

```css
.dimmer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 99;          /*  immeadiate below textarea  */
}

input, textarea {
   position: relative;
}

input.use-dimmer:focus,
textarea.use-dimmer:focus {
  z-index: 100;
}
input.use-dimmer:focus ~ .dimmer,
textarea.use-dimmer:focus ~ .dimmer {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>hello there, this is just a text to show how this work</p>

<textarea class="use-dimmer">sample text</textarea>
<br>
<input class="use-dimmer" value="sample text"/>

<div class="dimmer"></div>
```

Comment: @Darama Here is how you need to do

Comment: @Darama Click the textarea and all the other elements become semi transparent ... and if not, what browser do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you're trying to achieve is to focus the user's attention on the `textarea`. So, you almost have the solution. Apart from using the right value for `position` (as mentioned by @Andrey Fedorov), you should use the `:focus` pseudo-class as follows:

```css
textarea:focus {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #66dd88, -2px -2px 2px #66dd88;
}
```

This way, when the user clicks the `textarea`, it is made distinct from the rest of the page.
NOTE: From the tags you gave your question, I assumed you don't want to use Javascript.

Comment: I have edited my answer to something far more concise.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("focus", "textarea", function() {
    $("body").addClass("textareaded");
  });
  $("body").on("blur", "textarea", function() {
    $("body").removeClass("textareaded");
  });
});
```

```css
.textareaded .content {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.textareaded textarea {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
<textarea></textarea>
```